# How to call a stored procedure in Pre-SQL using Informatica?

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have created a procedure in DB12 PWX to delete data with where condition in destination table. In the mapping, I am just taking a table name from the sysdummy table and output is going to a file. In the workflow I am calling a SP in the PreSQL.

The stored procedure doesn't have output result it will have one input parameter (table name) itself. I tried to write different commands to call the stored procedure

CALL "abcdschema.sampleproc1"("mytable");

CALL 'abcdschema.sampleproc1'('mytable');

CALL abcdschema.sampleproc1("mytable");

Answer (score 0):

I believe the third option should work just fine - have you ran across errors?

In addition, you might check another way of calling Stored Procedure. Following the [documentation](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/transformation-guide/stored-procedure-transformation/configuring-an-unconnected-transformation/calling-a-pre--or-post-session-stored-procedure.html) you may create a `Stored Procedure Transformation` in the mapping. The advantage of this approach is it will be visible right there in the mapping, while using Pre-SQL hides that on Session level.

Although in fact it's most common to use Pre/Post-SQL as it requires far less development.